# Using virtualenv with python3 in openSuSE

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, opensuse

I am experiencing a problem when using virtualenv in openSuSE 12.3 with Python3:

I installed the `python3` and `python3-devel` packages.
Then I installed the newest `distribute` and `pip` and finally virtualenv using pip.

When I try to create a virtualenv I get the following error:

```
$ virtualenv-3.3 venv01
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in venv01/bin/python3.3
Also creating executable in venv01/bin/python
Installing distribute.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip....
  Complete output from command /home/user/venv01/bin/python3.3 -x /home/user/venv01/bin/easy_install /usr/local/lib/pytho...ort/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz:
  /home/user/venv01/bin/python3.3: can't open file '/home/user/venv01/bin/easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv-3.3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.9.1', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv-3.3')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 979, in main
    no_pip=options.no_pip)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1094, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 667, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1057, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/user/venv01/bin/python3.3 -x /home/user/venv01/bin/easy_install /usr/local/lib/pytho...ort/pip-1.3.1.tar.gz failed with error code 2
```

Running it with `-vvv` yields some interesting output that shows that `distribute`
is extracted to `<venv>/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/`.

I wonder why distribute is not installed into `<venv>/lib/python3.3/site-packages/`?

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how I can use virtualenv in
openSuSE without compiling `python3` myself?

Answer (score 1):

**[now fixed in latest patches from opensuse]**

[oh!  i just realised you are the same person as the original link.  sorry.  but i will leave this as it is a top result for google search on this issue (was searching myself for any update) so it may help others.]

this is a known issue, discussed at https://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/applications/484475-using-virtualenv-python-3-a.html and with an open bug at https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=809831

the only work-around i know of is to install everything yourself.  it's not so hard, and i describe what is necessary at http://www.acooke.org/cute/GettingPyt0.html

basically:

- install python 3.3 from source (do an "altinstall" to install as /usr/local/bin/python3.3)
- fix the lib issue (link lib_dynload from /usr/local/lib64/python3.3 to  /usr/local/lib/python3.3)
- install distutils
- install virtualenv

then you can use `python3.3` and `virtual-env-3.3` etc as expected.

Comment: Yep I know - I asked the question in the forums. I just had hoped that maybe someone on stackoverflow has some better understanding of the involved bits like `distutils` and `site`-specific customizations and might provide a pointer to solve it. The main problem when building from source is that I have to think about including things like `tkinter` integration from the start, which I am quite likely to forget or realize to late that I actually needed them.

Comment: indeed.  although (unlike early pythons) python3.3 does list the missing libraries at the end of `make` (so you still have to build it at least twice - once hoping it is ok, and a second time after providing missing dependencies).